# Geography for Sql Server STIsValid() getting error

Tags: sql-server, geography-data-type

I am getting the following error
Could not find method 'STIsValid' for 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography' in assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types' on the following query.

```
select ogr_geog from dbo.pod_1730_essential_energy
where ogr_geog.STIsValid() = 0 and ogr_geog is not null
```

All my other Spatial methods work. The ogr_geog column is a geography type.
Does anybody know the root of this error?

Comment: STIsValid() was added to the Geography type with SQL Server 2012. You don't happen to be using SQL Server 2008, do you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

STIsValid() was added to the Geography type with SQL Server 2012.

If you are using SQL Server 2008 this method only exists for the Geometry data type